# generalized mean for negative numbers

Tags: real-analysis, means

Power means are defined by
$$
\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i^p\right)^{1/p}
$$

where $p\in\mathbb{R}$, and the $x_i$ are *positive* real numbers.

I wonder what happens when some of the $x_i$ are negative. Then either the sum $s$ may be negative, in which case $s^{1/p}$ may be a complex number or $x_i^p$ is directly a complex number. I have two questions on this:

1. Is taking the power means in these cases still a well-defined operation? Does it have a semantics by analogy to the case when the $x_i$ are positive?
2. What could we do to remedy this? Adding a shift to all numbers, taking the power mean and then shifting back would be a solution. But does that make any sense?
3. Are there other forms of generalized means applicable to positive and negative reals?

Comment: $x_i^p$ is never a complex number if both $x,p\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Really ? $(-1)^{1/2}= ?$.

Comment: $p=1$ is the arithmetic mean while $p=2$ is the root mean square, both commonly used with negative $x_i$ (or rather mixes of positive and negative $x_i$)

Comment: True, and for $p=4,6,8,...$ and $p\rightarrow\pm\infty$ it also works. How about the general case?

Comment: @Fred As for $p=2$, the situation you posed will not occur since the sum of $x_i^2$ is always positive.

Comment: (cont.) Of course, I restricted $p$ to nonzero integers.

Comment: @LeiZhao Yes, let's ignore the trivial cases $p=2,4,6,8,10,...$. It's clear that they work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first apply an exponential to your numbers and take the logarithm of the result, i.e.,
$$
\log \left( \frac1n \sum_{i = 1}^n \exp(x_i)^p \right)^{1/p}.
$$
After some manipulation, we find that this is equal to
$$
\frac1p\log \left(\frac1n \sum_{i = 1}^n \exp( p x_i )\right)
$$
and this is similar to the log-sum-exp.
Note that for $p \to 0$, we obtain (e.g. by L'Hospital)
$$
\frac1n \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i,
$$
i.e., the arithmetic mean.

While the "standard" means are homogeneous (w.r.t. scaling), the above quantities behave nicely w.r.t. addition, i.e., if you increase all $x_i$ by $y$, the resulting mean also increases by $y$. This seems to be a desired property.