# A small error in an exercise from Apostol's Calculus I

Tags: means, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Recently, I started to teach myself calculus by reading Apostol's Calculus Volum 1.  I almost finished the introductory chapter.  However, I felt the condition is imperfect for exercise 17 from section 4.10 of the introductory chapter.

> *Inequalities relating different types of averages*. Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ positive real numbers. If $p$ is a nonzero integer, the *$p$th-power mean* $M_p$ of the $n$ numbers is defined as follows:
> $$M_p=\left(\frac{x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p}{n}\right)^{1/p}.$$
> The number $M_1$ is also called the *arithmetic mean*, $M_2$ the *root mean square*, and $M_{-1}$ the *harmonic mean*.
>
> **17.** If $p > 0$, prove that $M_p<M_{2p}$ when $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are not all equal.
>
> [*Hint:* Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with $a_k=x_k^p$ and $b_k=1$.]

I can construct a counterexample as follows.  Let $x_1 = -2$, $x_2 = 2$, and $p = 2$, then
$$
M_2
= \left(\frac{(-2)^2 + 2^2}{2}\right)^{1/2}
= \left(\frac{4+4}{2}\right)^{1/2}
= 4^{1/2}
= 2
= 16^{1/4}
= \left(\frac{16+16}{2}\right)^{1/2}
= \left(\frac{(-2)^4 + 2^4}{2}\right)^{1/2}
= M_4.
$$
I believe that the condition should be “when $|x_1|, |x_2|, \dots, |x_n|$ are not all equal.”  Is there anyone who can reassure me about my thinking?

Comment: He said all the $x_i$ are assumed positive.  It's the second sentence.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: But I don't see any reason to restrict pth-power mean to positive numbers.  At least when we talk about arithmetic mean, we don't usually restrict ourselves to positive numbers.

Comment: Maybe you can, but then of course the stated result may no longer hold.

Comment: I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2555304/147999, which is related to this question.